# Pull data from a google sheet with a for loop with javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, google-sheets

Is there a way to loop through rows of a google spreadsheet with only the link or the google sheet key? I need to do string manipulation with each of the values and save them to a database. Is there a quick way to return a string with google sheets?

Comment: [Yes there is](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/). Are you working in the browser? Server-side using nodejs? Have you tried anything? At all?

Comment: Im working on the browser side as it wont be used very often. I have tried tabletop.js but it refused to work. Also it gives me the entire thing as JSON instead of letting me loop through it. (to my knowledge)

Comment: tabletop.js seems to return a JSON array of data. Just loop over the array.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant access spreadsheet data without Oauth in javascript.

Better way is use Google app script (from tools -> script editor) write function to read spreadsheet data. deploy that web service publicly and do ajax call to that web service in your javascript you will be able to get all spreadsheet data. if it is returned from that app script function.